# Intel 8086 - Push command throwing up errors

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I'm supposed to modify some code for an assignment. My problem is that the code itself isn't working properly. I'm not asking for help with the task, just getting the sample code to work. That being said, any help is appreciated.

First things first, here's the code I;m supposed to be working with:

```
;Program to add two single digit numbers - answer must also be a single digit number.

.model small
.stack 100h
.data

prompt1 db  13, 10, 'Enter the first number to add:', 13, 10, '$'
prompt2 db  13, 10, 'Enter the second number:', 13, 10, '$'
answer      db  13, 10, 'The answer is:', '$'
num1        db  ?
num2        db  ?

.code

start:
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax
        mov ax, offset prompt1  ;prompt to enter first number
        call puts
        call getc           ;collect first number
        mov num1, al            ;and save

        mov ax, offset prompt2  ;prompt to enter 2nd number
        call puts
        call getc           ;collect second number
        mov num2, al            ;and save





mov ax, offset answer       ;display answer message
        call puts

        mov al, num1
        add al, num2            ;calculate answer
        sub al, '0'         ;convert to a character for display

        mov dl, al
        call putc           ;and display it

        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

puts:                   ; display a string terminating in $
    push ax bx cx dx    ; save ax, bx, cx, dx
    mov  dx, ax     ; address of string must be stored in dx
    mov  ah, 9h
    int   21h       ; MSDOS called to display string
    pop dx cx bx ax ; restore dx cx bx ax
ret

getc:   
    push   bx cx dx ; save bx cx dx
    mov  dx, ax     ; address of string must be stored in dx
    mov  ah, 1h     ; char read into al, and output on screen
    int   21h       ; MSDOS called to read char
    pop dx cx bx        ; restore dx cx bx
    ret

putc:   
    push   ax bx cx dx  ; save ax bx cx dx
    mov  ah, 02h
    int   21h               ; MSDOS called to display char
    pop  dx cx bx ax    ; restore dx cx bx ax
    ret

end start
```

The error it's throwing up when I try to compile and run it is on line 48, and is:

```
wrong parameters: PUSH ax bx cx dx
```

The line in question is:

```
push ax bx cx dx    ; save ax, bx, cx, dx
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is ages since I have done assembly, but can't you just push one after the other? `push bx`, `push cx`, `push dx` and the same for `pop` in reverse order.

Comment: What assembler are you using? The syntax `push <reg-list>` is supported only by TASM AFAIK

Comment: I'm using emu8086,  and I've got it working. Info in the edits to the OP

Comment: post your solution as an answer, not an edit to the question.  And never put "solved" in the title: click the checkmark on one of the answers to mark it as the solution.  You should revert your edit after (or before) posting your own answer as an answer.

Comment: Since Ross rolled back your bad edit, you can still find everything you typed by looking at the edit history.  e.g. the markdown source is http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0b148182-a3b3-4f59-adac-f215e026a6fb/view-source (from clicking "source" on revision 3).  I should have just explained this in my previous comment and rolled it back myself.

Answer (score 1):

Like already has been said by Axel, you'd run multiple of these push and pop instructions. Or perhaps it's also possible to push/pop all registers at once using the PUSHA and POPA instructions?

Comment: I have followed axels instructions and it now works. Extra info in the edit I've added to the OP